# Restfullroute for subscription between two models

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm working on a RestApi and I'm hesitating for the choice of a type of route.

I have `User` and `Collection` and some routes like :

```
GET /user
GET /collections
GET /collection/{id}
```

Now I need to add a route for a `User` can subscribe to a `Collection`, so what's the best route ?

- `POST collection/{id}/user/subscription ?`
- `POST /user/subscription/collection/{id} ?`
- Other ?

In my database for example, I have a table with :

- id
- user_id
- collection_id

Thanks !

Comment: I would use `collection/{id}/subscription/{userID}` or `collection/{id}/subscription/user/{userID}` I think them both is more readable.

Comment: I don't need userID, Only a connected user can call this, so I already have the id (or token)

Comment: so, I'd use one of them, without userID ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application, the concept of a *subscription* is the relationship between a *user* and a *collection*. There are many ways to handle it, but I would have a URI like `/collections/{collection-id}/subscriptions`.

### Creating a subscription

To create a subscription, I would perform a `POST` sending the identifier of the user that is subscribing to the collection in the request payload:

```
POST /collections/{collection-id}/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json

{"user": "{user-id}"}
```

In the future, if you need to add other attributes to the subscription (such as *expiration date*, *status*, etc), they should be sent in the request payload as well. You also may not need to send the user identifier if you assume the user that is performing the request is authenticated and is the one that is subscribing to the collection.

A successful response to this request should have the `201` status code and the `Location` HTTP header:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2016 11:00:00 GMT
Location: http://example.com/collections/{collection-id}/subscriptions/{subscription-id}
```

### Removing a subscription

To remove a subscription, I would perform a `DELETE` request:

```
DELETE /collections/{collection-id}/subscriptions/{subscription-id} HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

A successful operation should result a response with the `204` status code:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2016 11:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: Why a "s" for /collections/{collection-id}/ ? For me it's better with /collection/{collection-id}/ because you try to access one collection...

Comment: @ClémentAndraud It's just a good practice when naming REST collections and resources. In this situation, `collections` and `subscriptions` are REST collections that contain multiple resources of `collection` and `subscription`, hence the plural form. Your URLs would be like: `GET collections` for retrieving multiple `collection` resources and `GET collections/{id}` for retrieving a single resource from the collection.

Comment: Hum, yeah. So, for all routes for a resources, it's always with plurial. GET, PUT, PATCH, POST....

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Correcting: For all routes for *collections* of resources you should use plural nouns. It's just a *common practice* and you don't need to follow it in onder to have a RESTful API.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the use case scenario. If the client is navigating on a `User` resource before trying to subscribe, it might make more sense to do it like `POST /user/subscription/collection/{id}`. If it's the opposite (browsing the collections and choosing one - or more - to subscribe to), pick the first.

Also, if `Subscription` is a resource in itself, that contains a list of collections (?), and if you're going to allow the update of a large number of collections at once, then `PATCH` might be your friend:

Looking at the [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) (which defines the Patch standard), from the client's perspective the API could be called like

```
PATCH /user/subscriptions
[
    { "op": "add", "path": "/collections", "value": [ "24", "27", "35" ]}
]
```

Probably not a 1 on 1 match with your models, but you get the gist.